# Save Parent and Child in One hit to database

Tags: django, database, django-orm

I have Three tables.

```
class Parent():
    pass

class Child():
    parent = models.ForiegnKey(Parent)

class GrandChild():
    child = models.ForiegnKey(Child)
```

Now **Parent** can have many **Childs** and child have many **GrandChilds**, i mean 100's.

Is there any way to save the **Parent/Child/Grandchild** at the same time ? So we get only **1** database hit and Parent/Child/Grandchild are all saved. I know there is transaction available in Django, but as per my understanding (I may be wrong) transactions are not the solution to this problem.

Comment: Look into Django's bulk_create and bulk_update: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create

Comment: @webtweakers bulk_create is for creating bulk objects in a single query, but how I am going to reference the child with parent ? I think it's not the solution

Comment: You'll need at least 3 (bulk) create statements to insert this structure into the DB, and probably 2 select statements to retrieve the ID's of the GrandChild's when inserting the Child's and then the ID's of the Child's when inserting the Parent. You can put all that in a transaction, to make sure the whole structure gets rolled back on error, but it won't change the number of queries required.